# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 8 on Samsung 530U (500GB+24GB)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, ssd, samsung

I have Samsung 530U (model NP530U3C-A06CZ), which has 500GB HDD + 24GB SSD.

I would like to have dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 + Windows 8, but I don't know how I can do it.

According to my information both (Windows and Ubuntu) should boot from HDD and the 24 GB SSD disc is only for ExpressCache.

But I don't know:

- how to install ExpressCache for Windows 8<sup>**1**</sup> (there is no driver to download from Samsung support)
- how to install both systems without a DVD-ROM
- how to make the disc partition in order to keep the possibility for Windows to use ExpressCache
- I also want to make a HDD partitioned to 3 parts (Windows, data, Ubuntu + SSD).

Is there any way to do that without uninstalling Windows? If not, what's the correct procedure?

<sup>**1**</sup>I am thinking about ExpressCache only for Windows, Ubuntu is fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SSD but if you want to dual boot, you need to provide at least a spare partition on your Windows 8 for use with Ubuntu.

Next
How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows?
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Once you have the bootable Ubuntu installer on USB stick, boot up your machine with the USB stick and follow screen instructions. Make sure to only install Ubuntu on the spare partition you've created earlier.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This post which I wrote might help you to some extent to install Ubuntu on the SSD:
http://menatronics.blogspot.in/2014/04/running-ubuntu-on-24gb-ssd-dual-boot.html

Basically all you have to do is disable Intel SRT (if it's used) and then go to Windows power option and disable Windows '***FastBoot***' option. You have to do this if you want write access to your NTFS drives. Then load the live DVD or USB and install Ubuntu to SSD. Mostly `/dev/sdb` (I'm not sure , just confirm it). Grub will take care of rest of the things.

Now,

1. You cannot use SSD as a cache for both Ubuntu and Windows. It's
   just not possible.
2. ExpressCache is only for Windows 8 and it's an OEM install, i.e. you cannot download it from any website.
3. There are several posts out there on how to use an SSD as a cache for Ubuntu, if you're planning to install Ubuntu to the HDD.